PowerAutomate Desktop changing file format
I have a premium Power Automate Desktop, and it pulls a file from a SharePoint Document Library and runs a Python script to convert the file from Windows format to Unix format and then sends the file to a watch folder (where PAD ends) where an FTP server uploads the file to a Unix server.
When Power Automate Desktop performs the Move file(s) step to the watch folder it saves it to that server back to Windows format.  Is there a setting in PAD that does this?  I have tried running a PowerShell script to convert it after saving but it is not working.
Flow Step Causing issue 
Detail of step
Here is my flow where the step that is causing the issue
